# Encrypting email in Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data

Tags: encryption, exchange-server

I am trying to send an encrypted email using Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.

```
public void SendMessage(FacadeModel.EmailMessage message)
    {
        var item = new EWS.EmailMessage(_mailService);

        var handler = new SecureMimeMessageHandler();
        byte[] con = handler.encry("test", "me@mail.com.au");

        item.MimeContent = new EWS.MimeContent(Encoding.ASCII.HeaderName, con);
        item.ToRecipients.Add("me@mail.com.au");
        item.From = new EWS.EmailAddress("", "me@mail.com.au");
        item.Body = "test";
        item.Send();
```

}

```
public byte[] encry(string body, string to)
    {
        var store = new X509Store(StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
                store.Open(OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly | OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
                X509Certificate2Collection certs = store.Certificates;

                X509Certificate2 cert1 = GetMatchingCertificate(certs[1], "me@mail.com.au", X509KeyUsageFlags.KeyEncipherment);

        StringBuilder msg = new StringBuilder();
        msg.AppendLine(string.Format("Content-Type: application/pkcs7-mime; smime-type=signed-data;name=smime.p7m"));
        msg.AppendLine("Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit");
        msg.AppendLine();
        msg.AppendLine(body);
        EnvelopedCms envelope = new EnvelopedCms(new ContentInfo(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(msg.ToString())));
        CmsRecipient recipient = new CmsRecipient(SubjectIdentifierType.IssuerAndSerialNumber, cert1);
        envelope.Encrypt(recipient);

        return envelope.Encode();

    }
```

But still i am getting a plain email with no encryption in outlook. where have i gone wrong?

Comment: do you set body here with raw data ?

Answer (score 1):

I posted a suggestion on the [MSDN forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/00f3e9d4-2ba0-4c9b-8bd4-950b92f3067e/encrypting-email-in-microsoftexchangewebservicesdata). Try setting the ItemClass to "IPM.Note.SMIME".

Comment: it does not work for me .cant decrypt .error is "Sorry, we're having trouble opening this item. This could be temporary, but if you see it again you might want to restart outlook. An error occurred in the underlying security system. An internal error occurred."